# Ajax submitted form takes long time to process

Tags: ajax, performance, forms

I am wondering where this comes from : I have a 2 field form for a site that I am building and for some reason, the post request takes up to 13 seconds to complete, according to firebug... The script literally just sends an email in plain text with the user inputs and that's it, nothing complicated.

I am wondering where that delay could come from, any idea ?

Here is a link to a dev version : http://vps-sd.com/sd2012/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend not to click links to sites I don't trust, but it could be either

1) Network latency.  Are you on a vpn?  Where is the dev server hosted?  You can use `traceroute` or something like that to follow the request from the command line.

If both the client and the server are on your dev box this should not be an issue.

2) For really long requests, I think it is more likely something in your dev server is screwed up.  It could be the code, or it could be that the dev server is having some issues.  Did you log onto the dev server and look at its load?  Has some process gone haywire?  Has it used all its memory?  Did you add some simple benchmarking code to the application server?

You need to diagnose where exactly the slowdown is.